# Create a function to render correct array in React and take optimization into account

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, function, optimization

In my React Typescript component (see below) I created this function to render the correct array:

```
const items = () => {
    if (relatedItems && relatedItems.length > 5) {
      const copiedArray = [...sixGridData.items];
      copiedArray[5] = <ChildComponent show={show} />;
      const newData = { items: copiedArray };
      return newData;
    }
    return sixGridData;
  };
```

The React component:

```
const MyBlock = ({ relatedItems, show }: Props) => {
  const sixGridData = { items: relatedItems as Teasers[] };

  const items = () => {
    if (relatedItems && relatedItems.length > 5) {
      const copiedArray = [...sixGridData.items];
      copiedArray[5] = <ChildComponent show={show} />;
      const newData = { items: copiedArray };
      return newData;
    }
    return sixGridData;
  };

  return relatedItems?.length ? (
        <GridBlock data={items()} />
  ) : null;
};
```

Is there a more convenient/cleaner way to achieve same result? Also maybe in terms of optimisation I can improve it?

So when the array has more then 5 items, I want the 6th item to replace with `<ChildComponent />`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there really is a "cleaner" way to do it. Everything is a matter of taste.
You could use ternary expressions and slices if you don't like using a fonction :

```
const items = 
  (relatedItems && relatedItems.length > 5) ? (
    [
      ...sixGridData.items.slice(0, 5), 
      <ChildComponent show={show} />, 
      ...sixGridData.items.slice(6)],
    ]
  ) : sixGridData.items ;

return relatedItems?.length ? (
  <GridBlock data={items}/>
) : null;
```

but I wouldn't argue it is "clearner" or "more readable".
From a performance point of view, all of this is equivalent and pretty negligible for reasonably small arrays.

In case you are dealing with a large array and don't want to copy it, there is maybe something to do with iterators to avoid the copy.